# Change text dynamically with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a scenario, in my MVC application I need to replace all labels having text 'Bank Name' with 'Supplier Name'.
'Bank Name' label are used in various pages, so its tedious for me to find and replace all, because in future it may happen that again I need to change 'Supplier Name' with some other text.
Just to add, all labels have different ID and Name.
So I am thinking to do this using jquery, like I can find the labels, divs, td's containing  'Bank Name'  and replace that with 'Supplier Name'.

```
$("div").text(function () {
    return $(this).text().replace("Bank Name", "Supplier Name"); 
});​​​​​
```

But my concern is, I have some tables, divs which are generated through jquery and I need to above function document.ready which will be called on page load only and not when my dynamic tables, divs are generated.
I want to have this function to be working for dynamic elements which may come on click of button and contain 'Bank Name', I can't really go to each button click js and call a particular function to replace text.
Can it be done in dynamically? Thanks

Comment: Why not use a proper IDE and do a change all "Bank Name" to "Supplier Name" in the source?

Comment: You *can* use [mutation observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver). But I would strongly advice against it. It would be much better if you used a proper framework for such a purpose, else you should invoke the function with every jQuery based change.

Comment: This is almost the definition of an XY Problem.  It will also give a **terrible** user experience.  The user will load your page with it saying "Bank Name" and then, a second later, it will suddenly change to "Supplier Name".  That's not nice.

Comment: *"its tedious for me to find and replace all"* - to be honest, if you are using any sort of IDE, this is about a 10 second task - even without an IDE you can use a grep util ... not sure why it would be "tedious".

Comment: Using VS but the scenario is like, I need to change this for every other client, so if I can control this with js then that's much better

Comment: @freedomn-m I agree with this point, so I have a choice to go with web.config setting and set the desired text in appSettings and read label values from appSettings. I want to check if there is a better way to do this

Comment: Ok - I think I understand the issue now.  It's not that you have some text that you want to change, it's that you have some text that might change in the future.  Although a slight misnomer in this case, you can use `localisation` where you store the text in a resource (or other) external file.  This is already built-in to MVC but doesn't need to be used just for different languages - you supply an English file and then you can change that file dynamically to make updates.  Here's a starter link: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/778040/Beginners-Tutorial-on-Globalization-and-Localizati

Answer (score 0):

This may help yours and you can use setInterval method  it will hit every  second and find and replace text
      http://jsfiddle.net/2EvGF/4214/

```
 setInterval(function(){
        // call your function
  },1000)

 <div id="id1">
 <p>
   apple
 </p>
 <p>
   ball
 </p>
 <p>
   cat
 </p>
 <p>
   dog
 </p>
</div>

    $('#id1 p').each(function() {
        var text = $(this).text();
        $(this).text(text.replace('dog', 'doll')); 
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

Hope this help you. by using the contains you can search the text and replace it.

$('div:contains("test")').text("New word");

if you needed more details plz let me know.

more info:
https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_contains.asp

Comment: Well that will work, it is just that for dynamically created tables through js which contains 'Old Word'. I need to call this again on each function in entire project where such calls are made

Comment: Formatting your codes and links can make your answer better to read.